# postgres query multiple tables to check if a value already exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint, unique-index

I have two tables `A` and `B` each with unique constraints for `appid` and `name` columns to ensure `name` is unique for each `appid`.

However, now I also need to ensure that `name` value is unique across the both tables.

I can write `UNION` query to check this also but is there something like

```
select count(1) from ['A', 'B'] where appid='123' AND name='item list check'
```

Comment: You can JOIN the tables too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid race conditions, you will have to lock the rows. You could write an `AFTER INSERT` trigger like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION no_duplicates() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   PERFORM FROM a JOIN b USING (name, appid)
   WHERE appid = NEW.appid and name = NEW.name
   FOR NO KEY UPDATE;

   IF FOUND THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'duplicate values found';
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;
```

The trigger itself would be:

```
CRATE TRIGGER no_duplicates_a AFTER INSERT ON a
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION no_duplicates();

CRATE TRIGGER no_duplicates_b AFTER INSERT ON b
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION no_duplicates();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only retrieve records that are present in both tables :

```
select A.appid, A.name
from A
join B on A.name = B.name and A.appid = B.appid
where A.appid='123' AND A.name='item list check'
```